# Create cursor from both `DictCursor` and `PreparingCursor`

Tags: python, psycopg2

I would like to create a cursor which will make me able to fetch columns by name (using `DictCursor`), but I also want to prepare and execute prepared `SELECT` statements without calling `PREPARE` manually (in other words - by using `PreparingCursor`).

Is there any way to accomplish this? I can't use two cursors (I think) because I want to execute prepared `SELECT` statements and to address columns by name on the results set that `SELECT` returned.